# How To Launch Activity With Carousel

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, carousel

I've asked this 2x already and nobody has been able to give a straightforward answer (and quite often they are TOTALLY misunderstanding what I'm trying to do: so I'm going to ask this as simply as possible:

How can I start a new activity based upon which item in the carousel is touched?

I am very intentionally including NO custom source code. I'd like to know how this can be done out of the box (considering this is the first result when you Google Android Carousel - this posting should be quite useful to myself and others in the future if we can get a straightforward answer to this question.

### Source:

https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-carousel-view/source/browse/src/net/pocketmagic/android/carousel/

### Android 3D Carousel Project: MainActivity:

(where the magic happens / needs to happen)

https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-carousel-view/source/browse/src/net/pocketmagic/android/carousel/MainActivity.java

Comment: I've looked through your previous questions, and all the answers seem correct to me.  `How can I start a new activity based upon which item in the carousel is touched?`  Implement a listener that calls `onItemSelected` when an item is touched (selected), and start a new activity with an `Intent`.  What is the confusion?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
             if (arg2==8000){//arg2 is position of selected item
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SomeActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Like this, but really you need to learn Android a bit, and this Carousel library is already deprecated, and works like....

Comment: Can you tell me how I might be able to execute a different activity for each item in the carousel? (or at least more than one so I can grasp the concept)

Comment: and I need a carousel... is there a better option? if so - please let me (and anyone who finds this later - know if so!) :)